# substr из php в js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я хочу обрезать строку по краям, в php это можно сделать очень просто:

```
$str="url(asdasdasd)";
echo(substr($str,4,-1));
```

Результат: `asdasdasd`

Мне нужен эквивалент на js или jquery. Имеющаяся в js аналогичная функция `substr` почему-то возвращает мне пустую строку:

```
str="url(asdasdasd)";
alert(str.substr(4,-1))
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9xa0gzvg/

Comment: `str.substring(4,-1)`

Comment: @HamSter https://jsfiddle.net/tjcp15bt/

Comment: `str.substr(4, str.length - 5)` или `str.substring(4, str.length - 1)`

Comment: @Diskyp, имела ввиду что метод не `subst`, а `substring`

Comment: @Dmitry спасибо, так работает.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ оказался таков: `str.substring(4, str.length - 1)`, но для удобства я сделал себе похожую на php функцию:

```
function phpsubstr(str,start,length){
    if(typeof str!='string') return false;
    if(start<0) start=str.length+start;
    if(length<0) length=str.length+length;
    return str.substring(start,length);
}
```

И использование: `phpsubstr("url(asdasdasd)",4,-1)`

Answer (score 0):

-1 указать не получится поэтому можно воспользоватся хитростью с длиной элемента

```js
str="url(asdasdasd)";
alert(str.substring(4,str.length - 1))
```